# Derivative of a homeomorphism which is complex differentiable

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, derivatives

I came across this statement in my lecture:

"Let  $U, V \subset \mathbb{C}$ open sets, if $f:U \rightarrow V$ is a $homeomorphism^1$ which is $complex  \space differentiable^2$ $\forall z \in U$, then $f'(z)\neq0$ $\space$ $\forall z \in U$."

And I have the followings definitions:

$^1$ $\space$Let  $U, V \subset \mathbb{C}$ open sets, a bijection $f:U \rightarrow V$ is a homeomorphism if $f$ and $f^-1$ are continues.

$^2$ $\space$ Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ open set, a complex function $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is complexe differentiable at point $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ if the limit $ \lim_{z\to\ z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ exists.

I know this isn't true for a real function, but i can't find a precise argument for a complex one.
Any help or hints will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy thing to prove if you didn't take a course in complex analysis. Basically, the fundamental fact about complex differentiable functions is that they can (locally) be written as entire series:
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-z_0)^n$$
From there, one can prove that if $f$ has this form and $f'(z_0)=0$ (ie $a_1=0$) then $f$ is not locally injective near $z_0$, and therefore cannot be a homeomorphism.

These facts can be found in any textbook on complex analysis, but again are not trivial.

Comment: I took course in complex analysis and I have the notions that you cited, but we never did the proof. I will try to prove it by myself using your hints.

Comment: @Philip You knnow that $z^2$ is not injective. You need to show that $z^2+a_3z^3+\dots$ cannot be injective near the origin. One way to do this is by Rouche's theorem.

Comment: @Philip alternatively, if $f(z)=a_k z^k+ O(z^{k+1})$, prove that you can find an injective holomorphic function $\phi$ defined near $z=0$ such that $f(z)=\phi(z)^k$.